# How do i speed up even more EEVEE rendering?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a pretty big scene with eevee currently rendering with a GTX1060 and for a frame takes 11 seconds. I wonder, how can i speed up the frame render time even more to get even faster renders? Should i buy a new GPU or are there some tips to speed it up? Thanks!

Comment: If the animation plays at real-time, you could always just capture the viewport in OBS.

Comment: yes, its a thing but ill have lower quality and also i have soft shadows, wich cant be rendered in real time properly.

Comment: Agreed on the soft shadows. I usually render with super sharp shadows, so I don't normally think of that.

Comment: Ok, i also wanted sharp shadows to make rendering a lot faster, but thene i realized that some scenes looked very bad without soft shadows...

Comment: and also i think this problem will be solved bc im going to buy 2x Radeon 5700 XT... and those are pretty good gpus